# Настройка конфигов react, typescript, webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

Делаю расшерение для хром (`chrome extensions`)

Структура проекта:

```
./public/<br />
./src/img/xxx.jpg<br />
./src/css/xxx.css<br />
./src/popup/popup.jsx<br />
./src/popup/components/xxx.jsx<br />
./src/content/content.ts<br />
./src/content/cls/xxx.ts<br />
./src/background.js<br />
```

Вопрос к знатокам:
как настроить конфиг `webpack` (а может и другие) чтобы

```
./src/popup/popup.jsx (react)  собирался в ./public/popup/popup.html<br />
./src/content/content.ts       (чистый typescript) все собирались в один файл ./public/js/content.js<br />
./src/background.js      просто упаковывался и падал в ./public/js/background.js<br />
и всё с ./src/img/*.* и ./src/css/*.* переносилось в ./public/img/ и ./public/css/<br />
```

Заранее огромное спасибо.